# External PHP file - parcing data from echo outside the doctype in a HTML file

Tags: php, html, echo

I have 2 files: file1.php and file2.html. So in file1.php I have:

```
...
//some variables like $title and $message
echo '<p><h1>' . $title . '</h1></p>' . 
 '<p>' . $message . '</p>';
require('file2.html');  
...
```

And I want to `echo` it in the `center` tag of my HTML page. But here's what happens when I open file2.html in my browser:

```
<p><h1>Title</h1></p><p>Message</p>
<!-- And so the doctype comes AFTER the PHP input. This ruins the whole code -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-us">
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/script.js></script>"
</head>
<body style="background-color: #FBFBFB;">
<p><a href="/" title="Home">Home</a></p>
<p><a href="/contact.html" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a>.</p>
<p><a href="/forums/" title="Forums">Forums</a></p>
<center>
</center> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code that echo the title is used before displaying "..."

Your main page it should had the php extension instead of html.
After changing the extension insert your code into your  html tags like that:

```
<center>
<?php
     echo '<p><h1>' . $title . '</h1></p>' . 
    '<p>' . $message . '</p>';
    require('file2.html'); 
?></center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your center tag, you can echo your value like this:

```
<center> 
 <?php if( isset($title) ) echo "<p><h1>" . $title . "</h1></p>"; ?>
 <?php if( isset($message) ) echo "<p>" . $message . "</p>"; ?>
</center>
```

Note that you cannot use php if the file extension is `.html`. You need to change your file extension to `.php` before trying above solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would write the PHP as follows:

```
$var = "<p><h1>{$title}</h1></p>\n 
 <p>{$message}</p>";
```

Then name both files .php !

At the very top of your html (now php file) you put this:

```
<?php
include("path/to/file");
?>
```

then write this within your center tag:

```
<?php
echo $var;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is basic templating. You have a template that forms a shell around your content, and you want to embed content into that template.

Drk_alien and Console are on the money, your main problem is that you're `echo` statement comes before your `require`, so the output will follow that order.

A general solution is to make your template, `file2.html`, a container by converting it into something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-us">
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/script.js></script>"
</head>
<body style="background-color: #FBFBFB;">
<p><a href="/" title="Home">Home</a></p>
<p><a href="/contact.html" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a>.</p>
<p><a href="/forums/" title="Forums">Forums</a></p>
<center>
  <?php echo $content; ?>
</center> 
</body>
</html>
```

Then, in `file1.html`, you can simply have:

```
$content = "<p><h1>{$title}</h1></p>\n 
            <p>{$message}</p>";

require 'file2.html'
```

`$content` will be available to `file2.html` and `file2.html` can be a general template that you can reuse for other pages.

As for `.html` and `.php` extensions, it will depend on your server settings whether `.html` files can be processed by PHP. The default on Apache, say, is that `.html` will not.